# Generating pages from a database

Tags: database, authentication, friendly-url, inventory

I'm looking for some help understanding how to generate pages from a database to create a catalog of items, each with different URLs. All I can seem to find through google are products that will do this for me, or full e-commerce solutions. I don't want a shopping cart! Just an inventory.

Also, perhaps someone could recommend their favorite/the best simple login solution.

Thank you so much for your time and any help, suggestions, comments, solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just posted a thorough solution to [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1082349/page-generation-from-php-class/1082470#1082470) that is very closely-related to this question. I'll re-post it here for your convenience:

---

I would suggest using some of the MVC (Model, View, Controller) frameworks out there like [KohanaPHP](http://www.kohanaphp.com). It is essentially this. You're working in a strictly Object-Oriented environment. A simple page in Kohana, build entirely from a class would look like this:

```
class Home_Controller extends Controller
{
  public function index()
  {
    echo "Hello World";
  }
}
```

You would then access that page by visiting youur url, the class name, and the method name:

http://www.mysite.com/home/ (*index() can be called after home/, but it's implicit*)

When you start wanting to bring in database-activity, you'll start working with another Class called a [Model](http://docs.kohanaphp.com/general/models). This will contain methods to interact with your database, like the following:

```
class Users_Model extends Model
{
  public function count_users()
  {
    return $this->db->count_records('users');
  }
}
```

Note here that I didn't write my own query. Kohana comes with an intuitive [Query Builder](http://docs.kohanaphp.com/libraries/database/builder).

That method would be called from within your [Controller](http://docs.kohanaphp.com/general/controllers), the first class that we mentioned at the beginning of this solution. That would look like this:

```
class Home_Controller extends Controller
{
  public function index()
  {
    $usersModel = new Users_Model;
    $userCount = $usersModel->count_users();

    echo "We have " . $userCount . " users!";
  }
}
```

Eventually, you'll want more complicated layouts, which will involve HTML/CSS/Javascript. At this point, you would introduce the "[Views](http://docs.kohanaphp.com/general/views)," which are just presentation layers. Rather than calling `echo` or `print` from within the Controller, you would load up a view (an HTML page, essentially) and pass it some variables:

```
class Home_Controller extends Controller
{
  public function index()
  {
    $myView = new View("index");
    $usersModel = new Users_Model;
    $userCount = $usersModel->count_users();

    $myView->userCount = $userCount;
    $myView->render(TRUE);
  }
}
```

Which would load the following "View"

```
<p>We have <?php print $userCount; ?> users!</p>
```

That should be enough to get you started. Using the MVC-style is really clean, and very fun to work with.

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot of tools out there for generating a web interface around a data model.  I find [Django](http://www.djangoproject.com/) pretty easy to use.  Based on its popularity, I'm sure that Ruby on Rails is another viable option.